# How to parse the "src" of image tag in Django textfield?

Tags: django, django-templates

So I have code in my HTML template like this

```
<div class="blog-content">
    {{post.text|safe|linebreaks}}
    <p><img src="{{ image_dict.1.url }}" alt=""></p>
</div>
```

This above renders the image fine in HTML.
My view is like this

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
images = post.images.all()
image_dict = {}
for image in images:
    image_dict[image.image_order] = image.image
    print(image.image)

return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {
    'post': post,
    'images': images,
    'image_dict': image_dict,
})
```

Basically I'm setting it up so that I can render the images via {{image_dict.image_order.url}}

But I wanna render the images as per following to associate them with each paragraph of text like so

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. massa a posuere tempus, urna risus lacinia eros, et euismod.<a><img src="{{ image_dict.1.url }}" alt=""></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque.
```

The above is the content from within Django textfield.

However, while the code within the template evaluates to the image url, for example say for an image with order '1'

```
<p><img src="{{ image_dict.1.url }}" alt=""></p> becomes
<p><img src="/media/images/codewithlewis.png" alt=""></p>
```

The exact same code I typed in django's textfield (as written in above string)
remains like

```
<p><img src="{{ image_dict.1.url }}" alt=""></p>
```

within HTML and nothing gets rendered of course.

[A screen shot of this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kKFo.png)

I'm fairly new to Django but I feel like I have tried everything. How might I go about fixing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are storing a Django Template in a TextField (instead of your templates folder).

If this is true you need to use Django's Template Engine to render that TextField similar to how Django renders Template files.

Here is a full working example of how to render a string as a template.

```
from django.template import Context, Template
image_dict = {
    0: {"url": "https://google.com"},
    1: {"url": "https://amazon.com"},
}
my_template_snippet = Template('<p><img src="{{ image_dict.1.url }}" alt=""></p>')
my_rendered_template_snippet = my_template_snippet.render(
    Context({"image_dict": image_dict})
)
```

It may look like the following in your view.

```
from django.template import Context, Template
def post_detail(request, slug):
    # Get BlogPost
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug).prefetch_related("images")
    # Construct image_dict
    images = post.images.all()
    image_dict = {}
    for image in images:
        image_dict[image.image_order] = image.image
    # Convert my_text_field to Template
    my_template = Template(post.my_text_field)
    # Render Template using image_dict
    my_template_rendered = my_template.render(Context({"image_dict": image_dict}))
    # Set BlogPost.my_text_field to the Rendered Template
    post.my_text_field = my_template_rendered
    return render(
        request,
        "blog/post_detail.html",
        {
            "post": post,
            "images": images,
            "image_dict": image_dict,
        },
    )
```